# JPA mapping: Assositation which primary key is compound of composite primary key of one entity and one atribute of other entity

Tags: java, mysql, orm, jpa

If you are confused with title, i will try to explain what i was thinking.In matter a fact it's pretty simple.
I have 3 tables (there is more, but it's not important now), which i try to map, but it don't work.
Tables:

1) Poseta

**datumPosete**, **idKlijenta**, UkupnaCena, idMehanicara

2) Usluga

**idUsluga**, NazivUsluge

3) StavkaPosete

**datumPosete** , **idKlijenta**, **idUsluge**, Kolicina

I bold primary keys. As you can see primary key of StavkaPosete table is composed of primary key Usluga table and primary key Poseta table.
I apologise on my English, if I made some mistakes.
Also I am very grateful everybody who answer.

Answer (score 0):

So its CompoundIdentity then where the identity of one class includes another persistent object
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/orm/compound_identity.html